# Доступ к данным TVirtualStringTree из PyWinAuto - Python

Tags: python-3.x, pywinauto

Есть приложение, в котором основная часть данных выводится через класс TVirtualStringTree (это графический компонент Virtual Treeview, подробнее по [ссылке](http://www.soft-gems.net/index.php/controls/virtual-treeview)). Так же есть Pyton 3.6 и PyWinAuto 0.6.1.

Для того, что бы я был доволен жизнью, требуется научиться считывать данные из колонок строки (не знаю как описать понятнее: сам компонент - внебрачный сын дерева и грида. т.е. у каждого элемента второго уровня дерева есть несколько полей. как у записи грида), вызвать контекстное меню и кликнуть по строке. Или, хотя бы, получить координаты этой строки. Дальше я с помощью кастылей выкручусь, хоть это и будет некрасиво.

В питоне я разбираюсь слабо, но опыт с другими ЯП есть. Предоставить само приложение, или, хотя бы, скрины не могу.

Comment: Для начала стоит [взять отсюда](https://github.com/blackrosezy/gui-inspect-tool) Inspect.exe и просветить приложение (переключившись на UI Automation mode): видны ли все элементы дерева и их тексты. Если видны, значит с этим хотя бы можно работать.

Comment: Но, вообще, с Delphi гридами не всегда везёт. Если там взято всё лучшее от TreeView, то шансов больше. Если же это грид от слова грид, то нужно в исходниках самого приложения делать включение поддержки UI Automation: [см. вот этот проект](https://github.com/jhc-systems/DelphiUIAutomation).

Comment: К сожалению, элементы дерева не видны. При переходе по нему светится только указанный выше класс и никаких данных. И переделать его тоже не получится, к сожалению.
Я так понял, других вариантов нет? Если данных не видно, то и доступ к ним никак не получить?

Comment: Насколько я вижу, у них есть какая-то [реализация интерфейса IAccessible](https://github.com/Virtual-TreeView/Virtual-TreeView/blob/master/Source/VTAccessibility.pas). Так что надо в Inspect.exe смотреть свойства из группы IAccessible. Или включить там режим MS AA.

Comment: Как это ни печально, но, при включенном UI Automation, IAccessible отсутствует. Если выбрать MS AA, так же не видно этой группы. Ладно, будем городить кастыли и велосипеды) благодарю за помощь)